# Removing lower marker in error plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot one sided error plot in MATLAB. Here is the sample code and output. I want to remove the markers circled in red. Can someone please help me with this?

```
x = 1:10;
X1=rand(13,10);
y = mean(X1);
U= std(X1);
L=zeros(size(y));
errorbar(x,y,L,U,'--k','LineWidth',2)
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Try 'CapSize' property. But it works for all caps....

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2015b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in and documented way to do this. You can, however, use the undocumented `Bar` property of the `ErrorBar` object which is a `LineStrip` object. You can then remove the vertices of this `LineStrip` object that correspond to the bottoms of the bars.

```
% Create a normal errorbar plot
e = errorbar(x,y,L,U,'--k','LineWidth',2);

% This is needed on Windows to ensure that the VertexData property is populated
drawnow

% Remove the line strip vertices which correspond to the bottom bars
e.Bar.VertexData(:,(numel(x)*2 + 1):(numel(x) * 4)) = [];
```

[image]

Alternately you can use the following to change the width of the upper and lower caps.

```
% Create a normal errorbar plot
e = errorbar(x,y,L,U,'--k','LineWidth',2);

% This is needed on Windows to ensure that the VertexData property is populated
drawnow

% [lower_cap_size, upper_cap_size]
cap_sizes = [0, 0.1];

vd = e.Bar.VertexData;

% Create alternately 1's and -1's to add to multiply by the width and add
% to the bar centers
diffs = 1-mod(1:(numel(x) * 2),2)*2;

% Determine the differences relative to the center of each bar for the 
% lower and upper caps
lowers = diffs * (0.5 * cap_sizes(1));
uppers = diffs * (0.5 * cap_sizes(2));

% Replace the vertex data for the caps by adding the above differences
% to the bar centers
vd(1,(numel(x)*2 + 1):end) = repmat(vd(1,1:numel(x)*2), [1 2]) + [lowers, uppers];

% Assign the vertex data back
e.Bar.VertexData = vd;
```

> Note: This *exact* answer only works on R2014b - R2015b. In 2016a, The Mathworks changed the way that the `LineStrip` is used and therefore the `VertexData` property isn't in the format shown above.

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what i want but when i run the same code in my system using R2015b i get this error: "Matrix index is out of range for deletion."

Comment: @Rachel Are you running the exact code that you posted in your question?

Comment: @Rachel What does `size(e.Bar.VertexData)` show after running the first command?

Comment: size(e.Bar.VertexData)

ans =

     3    60

Comment: @Rachel Ok and what is `numel(x)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131745/discussion-between-rachel-and-suever).